# Gradle on Netbeans compiling Android Studio scripts

Tags: android, spring-mvc, netbeans, gradle

I recently added the gradle support plugin to my NetBeans to try some Spring framework tutorials.

Since then every time i run a project on NetBeans the output throws a list of errors.

**But the errors are not from my NetBeans Projects,** **they are from my Android Studio projects!** My NetBeans projects runs as expected, the Android Studio projects as well, and never thrown any warning on error since this on Android Studio.

What´s going on?

Comment: You need to tell us more details about what is happening. Have you installed Gradle plugin or Gradle plugin + NBAndroid (with its Gradle support)? What error do you see?

Comment: I installed Android Studio, it is updated. I use gradle distributions from local directory (version 2.2.1) and everything is fine in Android Studio.
Recently i installed gradle suport for my netbeans and followed the tutorials in [spring.io](http://spring.io/) and my project throw 
`org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.1-bin.zip'.` why?